# Microsoft Teams Connector Configuration page fails to load

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

As requested [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/msteams_tfb-msteams_teams-msteams_mngteam/cannot-configure-connectors-for-my-team/969e9c82-6561-49e3-bae4-ee9dcdd02880?messageId=486a5664-7ff0-42d7-be6c-4774fb2ad4fc) i am reposting this question.

I have the same issue as PitcherIT mentions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_teams-mso_o365b/cannot-configure-connectors-for-my-team/93c0c329-db94-432e-a309-a340c3bcb262?page=2)

```
I am trying to configure Connectors for my Team and when I click on the Connectors 
option, the sub pane starts to load and then errors with;

:-(

Something went wrong.

Something went wrong

RequestId: unknown
Server: unknown
Date: null
```

As the original thread is closed i am adding my experience in a new question.

I can add new connectors to the channel going via Apps>Connectors>Incoming Webhook
But i cannot view already configured connectors or change them due to the error message.

What i noticed is that the new webhooks have the format
`https://xtpgroup.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/`
while the old one starts with
`https://outlook.office.com/webhook/`

Maybe that is connected with the strange error message when viewing the connectors.

How can i change the configured connectors without deleting and recreating the whole channel?

Edit: [Screenshot of the Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syy9r.png)

Comment: Hello, Can you please share repro step with screenshots?(where you are getting that screen.)

Comment: I added a screenshot of the connectors configuration of the affected channel.

Comment: @CarstenR - Are you facing this only in one team or multiple teams?

Comment: Two channels in one team at the moment. As far as i can tell it affects all teams which have old webhooks configured.

Comment: @CarstenR - We got an update from the concern team. Can you confirm:
Is this happening every time? You should be able to access the Connectors page after retry after some time.

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT, I just retested and yes sometimes i can now access the connectors page.
When i can access the page i can create new connections but it seems i cannot configure old ones. The configure button just forwards me to the create page of the connector instead of the configuration page.

Comment: Hello, Just want to confirm one thing, In order to configure already configured connectors you need to configure from *Configured* under Manage section. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H9rU.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1H9rU.png). Are you doing this way only?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Hi, i just retested and now everything is working fine. Whatever way i choose to create/update connectors i no longer see the error message and everything is working fine. Thank you for fixing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have raised a bug internally. We will let you know about updates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/problem-with-configured-connectors-for-channel/6f3c07ed-bd69-4457-bc5c-730a6bb305ff) where I wasn't able to view Configured Connectors for a Channel in the Teams app. There wasn't an error message, but the loading icon never resolved. The workaround for me was to use the [Teams web app](https://teams.microsoft.com/) and configure Connectors there.